# Spring Boot with Angular on Raspberry PI (whitelabel error)

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, raspberry-pi

I have a frontend application and a backend, which I am currently starting separately on the Raspberry PI. I start the frontend with "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0" and the backend with “java -jar Backend.jar”.
Then I was able to successfully reach the UI under the url http://192.168.178.47:4200/.

Now I wanted to start the frontend with the Spring Boot (Tomcat). For this I followed the following tutorial:
https://medium.com/@majdasab/integrating-an-angular-project-with-spring-boot-e3a043b7307b

Now when I start the application and enter the url (http://192.168.178.47:8080/), I get a withelabel error.

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Aug 18 17:52:47 BST 2021 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
> Found, status=404).

What can be the reason for this and how can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to start them at the same time? If it's not for development, you should build Angular with `ng build --prod` (no need for --prod if using Angular 12)

Comment: Hey, so that I have both in one file and only have to start the Jar on the PI to start the frontend and backend.